# Run ClojureScript using nodejs while using another lein project

Tags: javascript, node.js, leiningen, clojurescript

I am writing a clojurescript program called "gpqgame" that evolves pieces of code; it evaluates the "accuracy" of a piece of code by running it on a simulator, called "qgame", which is a leiningen project in another directory.

So far, I have been manually loading all qgame code into a repl, and then testing my evolution code using that. However, I want to be able to run the code from the terminal, so I set up my gpqgame as a lein project, and have been trying to use nodejs. I promptly started running into trouble.

Gpqgame can't seem to load qgame and I don't know why, I've included the project.clj files for both. I've tried loading the full project as a lib and foreign-lib inside the cljs-build, and I've tried copying the "src" of qgame into the "src" of gpqgame while including the libraries that qgame needs inside the resources of gpqgame. My gpqame.core has the following ns declaration:

```
(ns gpqgame.core
 (:require [clojure.string :as st] 
              [qgame.simulator.interpreter :as inter] 
              [qgame.gp.evaluator :as ev] 
              [qgame.simulator.qgates :as qg]
              [clojure.browser.repl :as repl]))
```

and it contains `(enable-console-print!)` and `(set! *main-cli-fn* -main)`.

Each time, the compilation will succeed but will give warnings about:
  1) use of undeclared vars in the qgame code
  2) keywords and reserved words are not allowed as unquoted property names        in older javascript

When I run `node out/gpqgame.js`, I get a reference error saying "mathjs is not defined". One thing I noticed is that qgame uses 0.0-2156, while my gpqgame uses 0.0-2913. If I change the version of one of them to be the same as the other, they don't work anymore.

Is there an easy way to have gpqgame load the whole qgame project without me having to include it inside the gpqgame project?

Is this the best way to do it, or should I include it in the src of qgame? Why didn't it work when I did this, even though I included the libraries it needed? I'm not sure how much of this has to do with nodejs, and how much is due to bad setup by myself. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
(defproject gpqgame "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write this!"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"

  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2913"]]

  :node-dependencies [[source-map-support "0.2.8"]]

  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.4"]
            [lein-npm "0.4.0"]]

  :hooks [leiningen.cljsbuild]

  :source-paths ["src" "target/classes"]

  :clean-targets ["out" "out-adv"]

  :cljsbuild {
    :builds [{:id "dev"
              :source-paths ["src"]
              :compiler {
                :main gpqgame.core
                :target :nodejs
                :output-to "out/gpqgame.js"
                :output-dir "out"
                :optimizations :simple
                :foreign-libs [{:file "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/0.18.1/math.min.js"
                                  :provides ["math.js"]}
                               {:file "./resources/arndt.js"
                                  :provides ["arndt.js"]}]
                :pretty-print true
                :cache-analysis true
                :source-map "out/gpqgame.js.map"}}]})
```

And the qgame project.clj looks like:

```
(defproject org.clojars.hippiccolo/qgame "0.4.4"
  :description "Quantum Gate And Measurement Emulator, or qgame. A machine-instruction-level quantum computing simulator. Ported from Lee Spector's QGAME (written in Common Lisp)."
  :license {:name "MIT License"
            :url "http://http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License"}
  :url "https://github.com/omriBernstein/qgame"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2156"]] ;2156
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.2"]]
  :cljsbuild {:builds
              {:dev {:source-paths ["src"]
                     :compiler {:output-to "static/qgame.js"
                                :optimizations :whitespace
                                :pretty-print true
                                :libs ["~/computer/javascript/prototype.js"]
                                :foreign-libs [{:file "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/0.18.1/math.min.js"
                                                :provides ["math.js"]}
                                               {:file "./resources/arndt.js"
                                                :provides ["arndt.js"]}
                                               {:file "./resources/prototype.js"
                                                :provides ["prototype.js"]}]}}
               :prod {:source-paths ["src/qgame"]
                      :compiler {:output-to "static/qgame.min.js"
                                 :optimizations :whitespace ;Eventually do :advanced here
                                 :pretty-print false
                                 :libs ["~/computer/javascript/prototype.js"]
                                 :foreign-libs [{:file "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/0.18.1/math.min.js"
                                                 :provides ["math.js"]}
                                                {:file "./resources/arndt.js"
                                                 :provides ["arndt.js"]}
                                                {:file "./resources/prototype.js"
                                                 :provides ["prototype.js"]}]}}}
              :repl-listen-port 9000}
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0")
```

Comment: So qgame.util.math contains a line `(def math (js/mathjs))` which seems to be the focus point of the reference error, which points out `qgame.utils.math.math = mathjs();` as the problematic line

Comment: Not sure if this is the solution but qgame's `project.clj` is missing `:target :nodejs`, which is required for node's different `require()` semantics.